# Installing and enabling Xdebug on MAMP PRO

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug

I am trying to set up Xdebug on my MAMP PRO installation. I tried xdebug.org/wizard.php to get the correct Xdebug version with custom installation instructions but I got stuck.

According to step 4 in the [tailored installation instructions](http://i49.tinypic.com/33nvt5w.png) I should get the following output:

```
Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

But my output reads as follows:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

Next I try [the instructions](http://i48.tinypic.com/1247v37.png) at xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize because the tailored installation instructions advice me to do so.

I undo the first step by deleting xdebug-2.2.1.tgz and the unpacked folder and then I start at step 1 again. My input for step 4 is

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/phpize
```

and the output reads as follows:

```
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

My guess would be that I need to install php.h, zend_modules.h and zend_extensions.h but I can not find them on the web. How do I best proceed in order to install Xdebug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The creators of MAMP have not released the usual open source components package with the 2.1.1 release, so you'll have to do the following. php.h, zend_modules.h and zend_extensions.h can be found in the source code for PHP 5.4.4. Here's a link to the page with the source code: https://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.4.tar.gz/from/a/mirror

You'll want to extract that, and the move the folder to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include, creating the include directory if needed. I believe you'll need to run `./configure` from within /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php as well to generate the Zend headers. Then, try the instructions you found again.

Comment: Worked for me. Make sure you download it to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php, and NOT eg. /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php-5.4.4 or whatever your version is.

Comment: I had the same problem. I went through the steps and was able to build `xdebug.so` I replaced the `MAMP/.../php5.4.4/.../xdebug.so` file and rebooted apache. When I load a page with `phpinfo()` It no longer says `xdebug` is enabled. If I put the old `xdebug.so` back in place and reboot apache it says its enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked for me. You have to run

> ./configure

and

> make

to generate the missing zend headers.