# PhpStorm and Xdebug not breaking in Symfony2 Controller

Tags: debugging, symfony, xdebug, phpstorm

I have configured xdebug in MAMP:

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
```

I have configured a `PHP REMOTE DEBUG` in phpstorm, setup a `server` and placed a few breakpoints

If I place the breakpoint in app.php It will stop execution and load the debugger.

If I place the breakpoint in a controller it stops the execution and loads the debugger with info, blinks, and then says disconnected and all of the debug info is gone.

It also does this if I stop on a breakpoint inside of app.php and then click play. It will go to the next breakpoint inside the controller and then "disconnect"

Comment: What xdebug version you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is known issues with xdebug 2.2.0 on MAMP with disconnections you have mentioned, you need to upgrade to never version  >= 2.2.1.

Comment: I was running 2.2.0. I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912646/installing-and-enabling-xdebug-on-mamp-pro and ran through the same steps. I built the `xdebug.so` file and moved it into MAMP. After restarting apache `phpinfo()` no longer showed xdebug as installed. If I moved the old `xdebug.so` file back and restarted apache xdebug was enabled again.

Comment: I have created a new question about the issue mentioned in my last comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415789/xdebug-bad-zend-api-version-number