# Xdebug bad Zend API Version Number

Tags: mamp, xdebug

I am having trouble upgrading xdebug for MAMP. I was running version 2.2.0 and there was a known issue that I ran into: [PhpStorm and Xdebug not breaking in Symfony2 Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389916/phpstorm-and-xdebug-not-breaking-in-symfony2-controller)

I tried to upgrade to version 2.2.3 by following the instructions from http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

After downloading and extracting the xdebug tar I ran `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/phpize`

Here is the output:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

I then copied the modules/xdebug.so file into the mamp php5.4.4 extensions dir: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.

If I run `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php -v` I get the following:

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.

PHP 5.4.4 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2012 17:28:56)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

I have restarted MAMP and Apache and tried loading a page with `phpinfo()` and I do not see Xdebug listed. If I moved the old xdebug.so file back in place the error is removed and `phpinfo()` show xdebug as enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by running

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/pecl install xdebug` At first I was seeing issues with the Zend API number using pecl. I followed this post: [pecl installs for previous php version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561722/pecl-installs-for-previous-php-version) and set the following:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/pear config-set php_ini /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/pecl config-set bin_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/
```

Not sure if these configs had something to do with it failing before

Answer (score 2):

I have a MAMP server set up on a Mac Pro, I could not get xDebug to work. This was in my logs:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xdebug: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20170718
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

This can be fixed by installing the latest xDebug.so.  My problem with doing so was that is was writing to the wrong xDebug.so,not the MAMP server:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so'
ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so (copy(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted)
```

The second line of @Shawn's answer was the solution:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.7/bin/pecl config-set bin_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.7/bin/
```

I was then able to build the latest xDebug.so to the right directory using `pecl install xdebug`.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I've been strugling with this issue for hours! and now the version match, don't forget to verify that all the versions are the same after running command `phpize`, this will do the trick then run `sudo pecl install xdebug` now my phpinfo() shows in my case the latest version: 

Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies.